# Volume of a geodesic ball in $SL(n) / SO(n)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, positive-definite, symmetric-spaces

Crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404944/volume-of-a-geodesic-ball-in-sln-son

Question: **What is the volume of a geodesic ball of radius $r$ in the symmetric space $SL(n) / SO(n)$?**

Context: Let $M = SL(n) / SO(n)$.  We can view $M$ as the Riemannian manifold of real $n\times n$ positive definite matrices with determinant 1 endowed with the so-called affine-invariant metric:
$$g_P(U, V) = \mathrm{trace}(P^{-1} U P^{-1} V)$$
for $P \in M$ and $U, V \in \mathrm{Sym}(n)$ (symmetric $n \times n$ matrices).

---

Attempts/what I know:

(1) [Theorem 2.4 of this paper](https://publi.math.unideb.hu/load_pdf.php?p=509) (screenshot attached) provides a formula for the volume of a geodesic ball for any noncompact symmetric space.  However, I am not very familiar with symmetric space theory, so I am unable to parse what this formula says for $SL(n) / SO(n)$.
[Example 3.4.6 of these lecture notes](https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2021/fs/401-3226-00L/lecture_notes/symsp.pdf) give a formula for the roots $\alpha_j$ used in Theorem 2.4, and it is well-known the rank is $q = n-1$.  However, I do not understand how to determine the constant $c$.  I have an idea what the domain $C_0$ might be (the intersection of a sphere and a Weyl chamber--expressions for the Weyl chambers can be found), but I am not confident if this is correct.

(2) When $n=2$, we know $SL(n) / SO(n)$ is isometric to the hyperbolic plane of curvature $-1/2$.  However, I am looking for a formula for general $n$.

(3) It is well-known that $SL(n) / SO(n)$ contains a totally geodesic submanifold isometric to a hyperbolic space.  This gives us a lower bound on the volume of a ball.  However, this is not sufficient for my purposes.

(4) $SL(n) / SO(n)$ has constant Ricci curvature, so we can the [Bishop-Gromov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%E2%80%93Gromov_inequality) to get an upper bound on the volume.  However, this is not sufficient for my purposes.

[image]